# C# MVC4 Different versions of the application, one entry

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I hope some people can give me some advice / help me point in the right direction.
I develop a application. Application is written in c# and using MVC 4. The application is has multi-tenancy databases. So the information of customer A is in own database, not not accessable for customer B. Further is the membership stored in the customer database. So the users of A are in database of A, and users of B are in database of B.

The application will have sometimes pilots. In that case we have 2 versions.
For example: Version 1 contains customer A and B
Version 2 contains customer C

What I want is something where I have one entry, but the pages are version specific.

My idea was to create a proxy or something which has knowlege that customer A and B are running version 1 and customer C running version 2.
So when a user of customer A wants to login, he give his companynumber, username and password.
The proxy checks where the database of customer A is located and checks if username and password are valid.

I dont want to send the user to a subdomain or something. So the url stays: http://www.domain.com. (Can contain actions like domain.com/controller/action, but not something like http://customer-a.domain.com)

I hope some can give me some advice. I tried with a console app and HttpListner but didnt work. Examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Like they say there are nine ways to skin a cat. I would of course make use of entity framework and the repository design pattern to work around this problem.

I would do the following,

- Create the 2 .edmx files needed to access the databases using entity framework
- Implement the repository design pattern.

You will for instance have a CustomerRepository that would contain the logic to retrieve the appropriate data from the correct database.

Without any in depth knowledge of the applications business rules however it is difficult to provide you with a solution that will 100% suit your needs and you will unfortunately have to figure that out on your own. But like you said, you just want someone to point you into a direction.

If you are unfamiliar with entity framework and the repository design pattern, here are some useful links you can use to read up on it,

- [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj590134)
- [Repository Design Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/572761/Generic-repository-pattern-using-EF-with-Dependenc)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am using Fluent NHibernate and that works fine. The repository design pattern, not yet used so i will take a look :)